# Output the line number when there is a matching value, for each column

Tags: bash, awk

Say I've got a file.txt

```
Position name1 name2 name3
       2     A     G     F
       4     G     S     D
       5     L     K     P
       7     G     A     A
       8     O     L     K
       9     E     A     G
```

and I need to get the output:

```
name1 name2 name3
    2     2     7
    4     7     9
    7     9
```

It outputs each name, and the position numbers where there is an A or G

In file.txt, the name1 column has an A in position 2, G's in positions 4 and 7... therefore in the output file: 2,4,7 is listed under name1
...and so on

Strategy I've devised so far (not very efficient): reading each column one at a time, and outputting the position number when a match occurs. Then I'd get the result for each column and cbind them together using r.

I'm fairly certain there's a better way using awk or bash... ideas appreciated.

Comment: If you remove `r` tag, please remove `Then I'd get the result for each column and cbind them together using r?`.

Comment: That's just my cumbersome way of doing it. I think people appreciates if the person asking the question has thought about it first. Obviously it's not the most efficient way, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Better to show **attempts**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for (nameNr=2;nameNr<=NF;nameNr++) {
        printf "%5s%s", $nameNr, (nameNr<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
    next
}
{
    for (nameNr=2;nameNr<=NF;nameNr++) {
        if ($nameNr ~ /^[AG]$/) {
            hits[nameNr,++numHits[nameNr]] = $1
            maxHits = (numHits[nameNr] > maxHits ? numHits[nameNr] : maxHits)
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (hitNr=1; hitNr<=maxHits; hitNr++) {
        for (nameNr=2;nameNr<=NF;nameNr++) {
            printf "%5s%s", hits[nameNr,hitNr], (nameNr<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
name1 name2 name3
    2     2     7
    4     7     9
    7     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the below script :

```
#!/bin/bash
 gawk '{if( NR ==  1 ) {print $2 >>"name1"; print $3 >>"name2"; print $4>>"name3";}}
       {if($2=="A" || $2=="G"){print $1 >> "name1"}}
       {if($3=="A" || $3=="G"){print $1 >> "name2"}}
       {if($4=="A" || $4=="G"){print $1 >> "name3"}}
       END{system("paste name*;rm name*")}' $1
```

as `finder`. Make finder an executable(using chmod) and then do :

```
./finder file.txt
```

**Note :** I have used three temporary files name1, name2 and name3. You could change the file names at your convenience. Also, these files will be deleted at the end.

**Edit :** Removed the `BEGIN` part of the gawk.

Comment: You're setting OFS but not using it, redundantly setting ORS to the value it already has, using `>>` in the wrong way, putting conditions in the action area instead of leaving them in the condition area, and at the end of the script going to remove ALL files and directories that start with `name`, not just the tmp ones you created. There's other less important issues too.

Comment: @EdMorton : Thankyou for all the suggestions. Regarding the OFS and ORS, yeah ! I took them off. Initially I was experimenting with `printf` where I used them but then forgot to remove them when I changed my solution. Regarding the temporary files - I think I have no other option, in fact that is the reason why I left a note to the OP assuming he will choose unique file names. .

Comment: @EdMorton : Regarding `using >> in the wrong way, putting conditions in the action area instead of leaving them in the condition area` -  I didn't understand what you meant. Kindly explain it further.

Comment: @EdMorton : regarding the less important issues, I though of the `paste name*` as one like in the case of no match. But I am creating the `name1 name2 name3` files in the same order for `NR ==  1`. I think when I do `paste name*` these files will be pasted in the same order as they were created. Please correct me, if I am wrong. There is no `manpage` information on how to use paste with wildcards.

Comment: You're using `>>` as if you were using shell. In awk you'd use `>` in this context as `>>` does not mean the same thing in awk as it does in shell. awk scripts are made up of `<condition> { <action> }` statements - you wrote `<empty/true condition> { if (<condition>) { <action> } }` instead, as if you were writing C. You'll find wildcard expansion in the shell man page as it has nothing to do with any specific tool you are executing, e.g. paste, it's a shell feature. Get the books Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton.. that was very descriptive